# WIX installer icon from exe

Tags: wix

Did someone notice the problem with antiviruses when used exe file of built software as a icon file. I have something like this: `<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="$(var.....TargetDir)/SoftwareName.exe" />` and https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/ pointed my installer as a malicious (and pointed icon.ico as a dangerous file).

In the case I described, is the icon.ico the copy of SoftwareName.exe file? If it is, maybe there is a problem with missing cert signing of this file?

Most antyvirus software of our clients don't see the problem but some of them report a threat

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

WiX doesn't extract the icon during the build like InstallShield does. I recommend extracting the icon manually and pointing to that instead.